# phpBB forum, self hosting or not?

Tags: themes, export, hosting, forum, phpbb

I want to set up a forum using phpbb.
I've done that in the past by using websites that host it for you, for example:
http://www.phpbbweb.com/ , http://www.free-phpbb-forum.com/ or http://www.prophpbb.com/

These kind of websites are using the phpBB software.

I do not direcly want to register hosting and domainname because I'm not sure if people will actually sign-up, so I was thinking about making a free forum first on one of the above websites (or similar), and if people like it I want to export all the content(users, posts, maybe the theme) to a self hosted site wich I can build a website around and stuff.

Would this be possible ?(apart from the fact that it might be confising for members searching the forum)

Also I would like to know if it is possible to make your own themes(/styles?) for the free hosted ones.

Maybe this is a really stupid question but I'm wondering because at WordPress you have a big diffrence between wordpress.com and wordpress.org, for example the theme design.

Answer (score 0):

For others that are also searching for this:

I made a forum at http://www.prophpbb.com/
It is NOT possible to use ftp on your forum, however, there are a lot of themes avalible for use wich you can customise by changing the css sheet.

As a free user it is possible to send an email to the admins of the prophpbb website to ask for a backup of your forum.
This way you can incluse that when you 'move'  your forum.

As a premium member, you can backup the database yourself.